why can't stop sendgrid webhook sending data?
we created a webhook on sendgrid, it works fine. then we decided to disable it, but we found that it keeps sending data to the endpoint. then we deleted the webhook, the data is still coming in.
is this normal? does it have a cache for sendgrid?
